# jQuery animate() and CSS transition happening separately on same event

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I was playing around with CSS `transition` along with jQuery `animate()` in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/qzLprt87/5/).

However, when I combined the two, the CSS happens first, and then the jQuery animations happens afterwards, occassionally with a pause.

Both of the animations are bound to the hover event of the `<div>` (CSS: `:hover`, jQuery: `.hover()`), but they do not happen simultaneously.

---

In case you need it, here is all the code:

```js
/* DON'T MIND THIS FIRST SECTION ... JUST FOR CENTERING */
var div = $("div#fiddle");
var win = $(window);

var reset = function() {
    var wWidth = win.width();
    var wHeight = win.height();
    
    var dWidth = div.width();
    var dHeight = div.height();
    
    div.css({
        marginTop: wHeight / 2 - dHeight / 2,
        marginLeft: wWidth / 2 - dWidth / 2
    });
}

reset();

win.resize(reset);

/* THIS SECTION IS THE PROBLEMATIC ONE */
div.hover(
 function() {
     $(this).animate({
         marginTop: "-=50",
            marginLeft: "-=50"
        }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
     $(this).animate({
            marginTop: "+=50",
            marginLeft: "+=50"
        }, 2000);
    }
);
```

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #444444;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div#fiddle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #8888dd;
    border-radius: 100px;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

div#fiddle:hover {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- The HTML if you want it  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fiddle"></div>
```

(It's a bit hard to see in the snippet, but it can give you an idea, especially if you set it to full page. But it's best on JSFiddle.net)

---

Any idea why this is happening, and any solutions? Also, any thoughts on why there is sometimes a pause between the two events, and sometimes not? Thanks.

Comment: Is requirement to apply `transition` and `.animate()` simultaneously ?

Comment: @guest271314 This is just a simple project for me, so there's no requirements. But yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in all honesty I was tinkering. Remove the duration time (2000) from the animations in your jquery. Looks like the transition on the css handles the duration.

```
div.hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            marginTop: "-=50",
            marginLeft: "-=50"
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            marginTop: "+=50",
            marginLeft: "+=50"
        });
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sp2ufh4o/1/

Comment: Cool! It works! I would upvote but I've reached my daily limit. Gotta wait till tomorrow...

Comment: I'm not sure if it just runs a little slow on my phone, but I like the effect it has of floating; bubble like. Almost mesmerising (perhaps it's past my bed time?). Is this for a larger project? I'd like to see it if it ever comes to fruition.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it looks like it is moving strangely (the bubble-like effect you're describing. It seems that the CSS and JS animation functions are different. Do you know what the default transition functions for both are? If I set them to be the same, then it should be more straightforwards.

Comment: And @DarrenGourley no, it's not. If you want to take it to another level, go ahead with it! I'm just playing around. And yes, it's way past bedtime. GO TO SLEEP =)

Comment: Sorry, I really was just tinkering. I noticed there was a delay before the js animation, seemed about 2 secs, so I upped it to 6 which increased the delay. Which lead me on to setting it to 0, then just removing it entirely. Heh, the strange movement thing that's going to bug you is the part I like the most, it feels natural to me which I guess is why I like it. Unfortunately I don't know all the ins and outs of the transitions though, sorry.

Comment: Ok @DarrenGourley. I'm not great at tinkering, but I'm glad you helped. I guess I'll ask another question about the exact timing-functions for the animations.